# How to write an iterative function

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I have the next for-loop:

```
dfs_fixed = []
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs_fixed.append(dfs[i][dfs[i]['paragraph'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True))
```

where *dfs* is a list of dataframes.

I need to do a function from it. Here is my solution:

```
def append_to_list(data_list, function):
    data = []
    for i in range(len(customer_data_set)):
        data.append(function)
    return data
```

But it doesn't work. When I run:

```
dfs_fixed = append_to_list(dfs, dfs[i][dfs[i]['paragraph'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True))
```

I am getting:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Is there any way to create an appropriate *append_to_list* function?

Comment: what your code is trying to do, in plain English?

Answer (score 1):

`i` is only defined *inside* the function. You need to pass `dfs` alone as the argument, along with a function that takes an element of `data_list` as its argument

```
dfs_fixed = append_to_list(dfs, lambda d: d[d['paragraph'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True))
```

and define the function something like

```
def append_to_list(data_list, f):
    data = []
    for d in data_list:
        data.append(f(d))
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, when you run

```
dfs_fixed = append_to_list(dfs, dfs[i][dfs[i]['paragraph'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True))
```

You're already using a variable `i`. If it has not yet been defined, you cannot yet use it.

Also, in your example, you're using C-style `for` loops as opposed to Python-style `for` loops.

You don't need to do:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
     print(l[i])
```

Just do:

```
for i in l:
     print(i)
```

If you need both value and index do:

```
for i, v in enumerate(l):
     print('value: %s; index: %s' % (v, i))
```